# Compilar app Ionic para versão antiga do Android

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic, app

Fiz um app com ionic, e ao subir para o play store, ele ficou habilitado para androids > 4.1 , só que o app é muito simples, praticamente só faz consulta no banco de dados.
Alguém sabe me dizer se tem como compilar ele para uma versão anterior do android ???

Answer (score 1):

Entre na pasta principal do projeto.

Vá no arquivo **config.xml**. Você vai encontrar essas duas linhas:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15"/>
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="23"/>
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
```

Em *minSdkVersion* você escolhe o número da versão mínima que é equivalente a versão do Android.

Em *minSdkVersion* você escolhe o número da versão máxima que é equivalente a versão do Android.

Em *targetSdkVersion* você escolhe o número da versão que você quer compilar o aplicativo.

Para saber qual número entre no site abaixo e veja a lista:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Depois é só *buildar* de novo.